# Android: patch 9 file ruins main.xml

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

I have a file file1.png in my drawable folder. In main.xml I have an ImageView and display this file via the src property. That works fine. Now I copy a file file2.9.png into the drawable folder, but I am not using this file anywhere and I am not changing anything. Now I get an error marker that tells me that main.xml cannot find a file in drawable called file1.png. After deleting file2.9.png it works again. If I would rename file2.9.png into file2.png and copy it into the drawable folder still everything works, but of course I need it as a patch 9 file.

Any idea?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 9-patch image is most likely invalid. Make sure that all the outermost pixels are either solid black or transparent, that your left and top edges contain no more than 2 black pixels, and that your right and bottom edges are solid lines, not split.

Comment: Like many simple compilers, aapt (android's resource tool) may emit a number of cascading errors after the first that are unrelated to the actual problem. Read its output from the first error down, not the last error up.